# Number of summations for a Hartree-Fock (single-orbital as basis functions) method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, computational-physics, quantum-chemistry

The Hamiltonian for a quantum $N$ - body system:

$$\hat{H} = - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i}^{N}\nabla_{i}^{2}-\sum_{m;i=1}^{N}\frac{z_{m}}{r_{im}}+ \sum_{i;j>i}\frac{1}{r_{ij}}.$$

The first two terms can be written as $\sum_{i}^{N}h_{1}(i)$ and the last term as $\sum_{i;j>i}g_{2}$.

The action of the Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$ on $|\psi\rangle$ yields the kinetic energy term $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ due to the interaction effect term composing of colomb energy $\sum_{i;j>i}[\phi_{i}\phi_{i}|\phi_{j}\phi_{j}]$ and exchange energy $-\sum_{i;j>i}[\phi_{i}\phi_{j}|\phi_{j}\phi_{i}]$.

Our focus is only on the colomn energy.

A spatial - orbital $\phi_{i}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of basis function $\chi_{m}$:

$\phi_{i} = \sum_{m}c_{mi}\chi_{m}$.

Then,
$[\phi_{i}\phi_{i}|\phi_{j}\phi_{j}] = \langle\phi_{i}(1)\phi_{j}(2)|\frac{1}{r_{12}}|\phi_{i}(1)\phi_{j}(2)\rangle$ and expanding it out in terms of basis functions gives
$\sum_{m,n,m',n'C_{mi}C_{nj}C_{m'i}C_{n'j}}\langle\chi_{m}(1)\chi_{n}(2)|\frac{1}{r_{12}}|\chi_{m'}(1)\chi_{n'}(2)$

It is claimed that the number of summations needed is $N^{4}$. Why?

Note:

1. $[..|..]$ is a chemist notation to describe inner product of wavefunctions.
2. $\phi_{i}(electron-index)$ describes a single - electron spatial orbit with $i$ being the index of a single - electron orbital.

Comment: Please give a reference.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I have addressed this: author made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, okay. But for the future, please provide references (I think it is clear why?!). Also, make a google search before asking. (I tried and instantly found a lot of references stating the correct result).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure where this $\mathcal{O}(N^4)$ claim comes from ($N$ being the number of electrons), but it is not true in general. Instead, the correct scaling is $\mathcal{O}(M^4)$, where $M$ is the number of atomic basis functions used in the expansion of molecular orbitals.

If your (spatial) molecular orbitals are expanded using $M$ atomic orbitals:
$$
\phi_p(\vec{r})=\sum_{\mu=1}^{M}C_{\mu p}\chi_\mu(\vec{r}) \ ,
$$
then the two-electron integrals read
$$
\langle\phi_p\phi_q|W|\phi_r\phi_s\rangle=
\sum_{\mu,\nu,\rho,\sigma=1}^M
C^{*}_{\mu p}C^{*}_{\nu q}C_{\rho r}C_{\sigma s}
\langle\chi_\mu\chi_\nu|W|\chi_\rho\chi_\sigma\rangle \ .
$$
This contains four nested, independent summations over atomic orbitals, meaning that the computation of a *single* element of the two-electron integrals requires $M^4$ operations, that is, it has an $\mathcal{O}(M^4)$ scaling. If you are using a smaller basis set, then $N$ and $M$ are comparable, so $N\sim M$ and $\mathcal{O}(N^4)\sim\mathcal{O}(M^4)$ might make sense, but not in general.

The naive computation of *all* two-electron integrals would then scale as $\mathcal{O}(M^8)$ (as $M^4$ integrals must be calculated, each of them requiring $\mathcal{O}(M^4)$ steps), or $\mathcal{O}(N^4M^4)$ if you only need the integrals of occupied orbitals. This naive implementation would be extremely slow, but luckily, it can be replaced by four $\mathcal{O}(M^5)$ procedures. One only needs to do the transformations step-by-step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle\phi_p\chi_\nu|W|\chi_\rho\chi_\sigma\rangle
&=
\sum_{\mu=1}^M
C^{*}_{\mu p}
\langle\chi_\mu\chi_\nu|W|\chi_\rho\chi_\sigma\rangle \ , \\
\langle\phi_p\phi_q|W|\chi_\rho\chi_\sigma\rangle
&=
\sum_{\nu=1}^M
C^{*}_{\nu q}
\langle\phi_p\chi_\nu|W|\chi_\rho\chi_\sigma\rangle \ , \\
\langle\phi_p\phi_q|W|\phi_r\chi_\sigma\rangle
&=
\sum_{\rho=1}^M
C_{\rho r}
\langle\phi_p\phi_q|W|\chi_\rho\chi_\sigma\rangle \ , \\
\langle\phi_p\phi_q|W|\phi_r\phi_s\rangle
&=
\sum_{\sigma=1}^M
C_{\sigma s}
\langle\phi_p\phi_q|W|\phi_r\chi_\sigma\rangle \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that this is why the second-order Moller-Plesset energy correction is said to have an $\mathcal{O}(M^5)$ computational scaling, even though the energy formula itself only contains four nested summations over molecular orbitals. In cases when even the $\mathcal{O}(M^5)$ scaling is too much, one can use approximations, like density-fitting to further reduce the computational cost.

Comment: You are correct - I've clarified with the author of the notes and there indeed is a mistake. The total number of summations is the number of basis functions to the power of $4$.